# VB.net updating Oracle record ExecuteNonQuery problem

Tags: vb.net, oracle, oracle10g, sql-update, executenonquery

Hey all when i use TOAD to update a table all works just fine when using this query:

```
Update CSR.CSR_EAI_SOURCE ces 
        Set (STATUS_CODE, COMPLETE_DATE, DATA) =
            (SELECT 'ERROR', '', REPLACE(REPLACE(c.Data, '…', ' '), '’','''') 
             FROM CSR.CSR_EAI_SOURCE C
             WHERE c.EID = ces.EID
               AND c.STATUS_CODE = 'ERROR')
        WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                       FROM CSR.CSR_EAI_SOURCE C
                       WHERE c.EID = ces.EID
                         AND c.STATUS_CODE = 'ERROR');
```

However, once i try doing the same thing in my VB.net program using this code:

```
 Dim OracleCommand As New OracleCommand()
 Dim ra As Integer

 OracleCommand = New OracleCommand("UPDATE   CSR.CSR_EAI_SOURCE ces " & _
                                      "SET      (STATUS_CODE, COMPLETE_DATE, DATA) = " & _
                                                "(SELECT    'ERROR', '', REPLACE(REPLACE(c.Data, '…', ' ' ), '’','''') " & _
                                                "FROM       CSR.CSR_EAI_SOURCE C " & _
                                                "WHERE      (c.EID = ces.EID) " & _
                                                "AND        c.STATUS_CODE = 'ERROR') " & _
                                      "WHERE    EXISTS (SELECT 1 " & _
                                      "FROM     CSR.CSR_EAI_SOURCE C " & _
                                      "WHERE    (c.EID = ces.EID) " & _
                                      "AND      c.STATUS_CODE = 'ERROR')", OracleConnection)

  Try
      ra = OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
      OracleConnection.Close()
      MsgBox("done")
  Catch ex As Exception
      MsgBox("ERROR: " & Err.Description & " " & Err.Number)
      OracleConnection.Close()
  End Try
```

It stays on the **ra = OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()** continuously until i get the error

> The CLR has been unable to transition from COM context 0x3327fa8 to COM context 0x3328118 for 60 seconds. The thread that owns the destination context/apartment is most likely either doing a non pumping wait or processing a very long running operation without pumping Windows messages. This situation generally has a negative performance impact and may even lead to the application becoming non responsive or memory usage accumulating continually over time. To avoid this problem, all single threaded apartment (STA) threads should use pumping wait primitives (such as CoWaitForMultipleHandles) and routinely pump messages during long running operations.

What could i do in order to get this working within VB.net since it works just fine in TOAD when running that same query?

Thanks!

David

Comment: when you run the query in TOAD, does it take a long time to execute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also turn off that ContextSwitchDeadlock was detected exception:

> To avoid these error popups from
>   appearing, select Exceptions from the
>   Debug menu from Visual Studio window
>   and in the Exception Dialog box select
>   the Managed Debugging Assistants
>   Exception Node. Then select
>   ContextSwitchDeadlock and remove the
>   select from Thrown column

from http://dotnetdud.blogspot.com/2009/01/clr-has-been-unable-to-transition-from.html

**EDIT:Check for Locks**

```
SELECT LPAD(' ',DECODE(l.xidusn,0,3,0)) || l.oracle_username "User Name",
o.owner, o.object_name, o.object_type
FROM v$locked_object l, dba_objects o
WHERE l.object_id = o.object_id
ORDER BY o.object_id, 1 desc;
```

do note you will need ability to see dba_objects as well as v$locked_object (pulled this from [here](http://www.dbasupport.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-43760.html))

and check out this article
http://www.orafaq.com/node/854

Comment: I already tried to turn off the ContextSwitchDeadlock at which all it does it just sit there doing nothing still on the **ra = OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()** line.

Comment: @StealthRT could there be a lock on the table and it is waiting for the lock to be resolved?  try committing in your TOAD session to see if you have opened an exclusive lock on it; how long does it take for the update in TOAD?  the results should be about the same regardless of where you instigate the query.

Comment: @Harrison: How would i go about checking to see if there is a lock on it or not?

Comment: @StealthRT I added a query above and a link that I took that from!

Comment: @Harrison: It tells me **ORA-00942: table or view does not exist** and points to the **dba_objects**.

Comment: @StealthRT you do not have rights to query dba_objects then (your DBA ought to be able to tell you though). Close down TOAD if you can (or commit/rollback everything) and give it another try.  Since it works in TOAD I would bet it is TOAD that has the lock.

Comment: @Harrison: Yet, TOAD had it locked i guess. I closed it down and ran the query from VB.net and it worked just fine :o)

Comment: @StealthRT Perfect!  those can just be nightmares to get working when things are working like that!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the query takes a very long time to execute, so the UI is blocking. The best solution would be to run this query in a different thread, so that it doesn't block the UI... or optimize your query so that it runs faster.

Comment: OK I've tried to put it into a background working but it has the same effect.. takes a long time on the execute and never does anything but instead of showing that error it shows nothing and keeps going....I did a **ctrl+break** and the **green arrow** is still on the **ra = OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()**.

Comment: OK then I'd follow Harrison's advice, there must be a lock preventing the query to complete.